# 5 GHz Band selection in Wi-Fi connection

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

What are the prerequisites of using 5 GHz wireless connection?

In order to use 5 GHz Wi-Fi connection, Do I have to select 5 GHz band only in adapter or in wireless router or both?

Can 5 GHz wireless adapter connect to 2.4 GHz wireless router(backward compatible) and vice versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the AP and the client have to support 5GHz (the hardware must be capable of it, and the software configuration must have it enabled).

Most client devices that support 5GHz also support 2.4GHz.

Most APs that support 5GHz today are simultaneous dual-band devices, which means they're really like a 5GHz AP plus a 2.4GHz AP both operating simultaneously in the same box.

Lots of 2.4GHz-only clients and APs exist. Those devices cannot make 5GHz connections.

If you really had a 5GHz-only client, which is very rare, it would not be able to connect to a 2.4GHz AP. If you really had a 5GHz-only AP, a 2.4GHz-only client would not be able to connect to it.

If your AP is simultaneous dual-band and your client supports both bands, then to guarantee the client makes a 5GHz connection, you need to make sure the AP's 5GHz SSID (network name) is different from its 2.4GHz SSID. Otherwise it's up to the client to choose which band to use when connecting to that AP, and it may choose 2.4GHz under some conditions.

Comment: I concur with this answer, however just for clarification: **AP = Access Point** (Device that broadcasts wireless signals but does not always work like a router) - Not all 5Ghz signals are the same, some devices cannot see 5Ghz if it is from another country, ie; Japan. Or if the device is using a dedicated frequency that is built for point to point connections. Though you will probably not run into this.

Comment: Can 2.4 GHz wireless client see/find 5 GHz SSID networks in the range? Can 5 GHz wireless client see/find 2.4 GHz SSID networks in the range?

Is there any criteria of wireless networks found by wireless client in the range? Is there any possibility that SSID is filtered out?

How can I determine band (2.4 and 5 GHz) information of wireless networks in my range?

Comment: Yes, as long as those two networks (Wireless networks) are on the same subnet, or LAN or VLAN, they will be able to see each other. Unless you have isolation setup and the router is disallowing local network communication.

Comment: As far as dertermining what frequencies your wireless can connect to, you will need to get the hardware info from the manufacturer. If you google the  HW DEV #, you should be able to get it from the google search.

Comment: @cengbrecht: As per above reply by Spiff, 2.4 GHz only wireless adapter can not make 5 GHz connection because windows will not be able to see 5 GHz signals broadcast by dual band router.

Comment: @Alex  - Though this is true, I wanted to be more specific for him to understand a way to get the information. Not everyone uses the basic windows info, sometimes they just want more information.